# How to get property from log configuration inside the code?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have an file with logger configuration. I started my Spring application with param:

`-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:/home/project/log4j2.properties`

For example i want to get property *appender.rolling.layout.pattern* inside the code? I don't want to use InputStream and read directly read the file. Can i get it from environment context? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use System.getProperty, explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

> The System class has two different versions of getProperty. Both
> retrieve the value of the property named in the argument list. The
> simpler of the two getProperty methods takes a single argument, a
> property key For example, to get the value of path.separator, use the
> following statement:
>
> ```
> System.getProperty("path.separator");
> ```

So this should do the trick:

```
System.getProperty("log4j2.configurationFile");
```

Comment: i need to get property which is inside the property file.
```System.getProperty("appender.rolling.layout.pattern");```
does not work

Comment: @oborigenn11 I see I have misunderstood. You may have to just read the file manually yourself.

Comment: i write in question that i dont want read it manually

Answer (score 0):

Basically **you can't**: once the `Configuration` is initialized, the `ConfigurationSource` is no longer available.

You can however loop through the runtime components and retrieve the properties you want. For example if you want to log all `filePattern` properties of the configured `RollingFileAppender`s, you can use:

```java
final LoggerContext ctx = LogManager.getContext(false);
if (ctx instanceof org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) {
    final Configuration config = ((org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) ctx)
            .getConfiguration();
    final LoggerConfig rootLogger = config.getRootLogger();
    for (final Appender appender : rootLogger.getAppenders().values()) {
        if (appender instanceof RollingFileAppender) {
            final RollingFileAppender rfa = (RollingFileAppender) appender;
            logger.info("Found appender with name {} and file pattern {}.", rfa.getName(),
                    rfa.getFilePattern());
        }
    }
}
```

However there is no hard rule on where to find the property or whether it is even available in runtime: e.g. many `Appender` properties are stored in their managers. To provide another example: the `append` property of file appenders is only available through reflection on the `OutputStream` underlying the appender.